# Android: Masking bitmap using Canvas and path not following dimensions and position

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, mask

I'm trying to create an Android app that let's the use choose a picture and use a template to crop it. The template could also be rotated:

The black translucent box with the triangle in the middle is the template. The idea is on clicking the button at the top left, the intersect of the background picture and the template would be left.

The second image is the desired result, the third image is the result I get instead.

The position is incorrect (it does not follow the coordinates written below the button). The dimensions are also incorrect. The scale is correct.

Here is my code so far:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);    

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
Path path = new Path();
path.lineTo(template.topleftx, template.toplefty);
path.lineTo(template.toprightx,template.toprighty);
path.lineTo(template.bottomrightx,template.bottomrighty);
path.lineTo(template.bottomleftx,template.bottomlefty);
path.lineTo(template.topleftx,template.toplefty);    

canvas.drawPath(path, paint);    

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);    

imageView1.setImageBitmap(result);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: you have shown undesired result but haven't shown the desired one

Comment: Sorry about that! Here's the effect I wanted: http://imgur.com/VtS31xf I will also update my question.

Comment: did you try `BitmapShader`?

Comment: I need the final image to be cropped. I just realized that Canvas wasn't really cutting the image, but just masking it. :(

Comment: so crop the result, whats hard with it?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: see `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`